# Skrollr - Sticky navbar not sticky

Tags: javascript, css, skrollr

I am using `Skrollr` to monitor events when scrolling a page.

I want to make a navbar, which is originally located at the middle of the page.

When a user scrolls until the navbar touches the top part of the viewport, it becomes `position:fixed` and stays at the top.However it doesn't work.

P.S. It has to run on mobile, so all the content should be put in `#skrollr-body`

The fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LnbC5/3/

EDIT: To better illustrate the problem, here is the entire code. I run it on iPhone and then I got stuck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="//rawgithub.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/master/dist/skrollr.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .header{width: 100%; height: 40px; background: black;}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="skrollr-body">
        <div class="huge-div">
            spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br></div>

        <div class="header" data-0="position: static;" data-top="position: fixed; top:!0;"></div>    
                spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br><br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br><br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>spacer<br>

        <!-- div below is working -->
        <div data-0="background-color:rgb(0,0,255);transform[bounce]:rotate(0deg);" data-bottom="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);transform[bounce]:rotate(360deg);" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255); -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);">WOOOT</div>

        </div>

        <script>
            skrollr.init()
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see what you mean by the demo you gave. When I scroll down, and the navbar touches the top, it remains fixed and scrolls along, I guess that is what you are trying to achieve. If I am wrong, please clearify your question.

Comment: Yes, it works on desktop... But when on mobile phones, it does not work :( If you use iPhone emulator in Chrome u will be able to replicate the problem

Comment: `position:fixed` doesn't work inside elements which use CSS tranforms (which the skrollr-body does on mobile). There's no straight forward solution. You could for example use two elements, one inside skrollr-body and the other outside of it and trigger the visibility of them.